# Como inserir/salvar string RTF - ASPxRichEdit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, aspx, aspxrichedit

Na minha aplicação, busco do banco de dados uma string que contém RTF e preciso carregá-la no ASPxRichEdit. E, quando necessário, salvar o conteúdo do ASPxRichEdit em uma string RTF para armazenar no banco de dados. Como posso fazer isso em C#?

Consegui indiretamente através da criação de arquivos para abrir/salvar, mas é inviável por questão de performance. Ou seja, a forma abaixo é inviável.

arquivo.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rtf = BuscaTexto();
    string open = @"Projects/PCMSO/PCMSO/App_Data/WorkDirectory/open" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".rtf";
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(open);
    writer.WriteLine(rtf);
    writer.Close();
    ASPxRichEdit1.Open(open);

    Delete(open);
}

public string Save()
{
    string salvo = @"Projects/PCMSO/PCMSO/App_Data/WorkDirectory/save" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
    ASPxRichEdit1.SaveCopy(salvo);
    string rtf_string = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(salvo);

    Delete(salvo);

    return rtf_string;
}
```

arquivo.aspx

```
<td>                                                                            
   <form runat="server">
      <dx:ASPxRichEdit ID="ASPxRichEdit1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" runat="server" WorkDirectory="~\App_Data\WorkDirectory"></dx:ASPxRichEdit>
   </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Inclua o seu markup

Comment: E seus arredores

Comment: @lucaswmloin, você leu a documentação do componente que eu passei pra você na outra pergunta?

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/119372/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Rich-Text-Editor/Examples/How-to-Insert-RTF-text-to-a-document

Comment: Sim, mas não está dando certo.

Comment: Então inclua em sua pergunta o erro apresentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui **inserir** a string RTF no documento, da seguinte forma:

*arquivo.aspx.cs*

```
protected void ASPxRichEdit1_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
   string rtf = BuscaTexto();

   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   ASPxRichEdit1.SaveCopy(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.Rtf);
   memoryStream.Position = 0;

   var server = new RichEditDocumentServer();
   server.LoadDocument(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.Rtf);
   var pos = server.Document.CreatePosition(Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameter));
   server.Document.InsertRtfText(pos, rtf);

   memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   server.SaveDocument(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.Rtf);
   ASPxRichEdit1.Open(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DocumentFormat.Rtf, () =>
   {
       return memoryStream.ToArray();
   });
}
```

*arquivo.aspx*

```
<script>
    var startPosition = -1;
    function OnClick(s, e) {
        startPosition = rich.selection.intervals[0].start;
        rich.PerformCallback(startPosition);
    }
</script>

<td>
   <form runat="server">
        <dx:ASPxRichEdit ID="ASPxRichEdit1" ClientInstanceName="rich" style="width: 100%; height: 600px" runat="server" WorkDirectory="~\App_Data\WorkDirectory" OnCallback="ASPxRichEdit1_Callback"></dx:ASPxRichEdit>
   </form>
</td>
```

Consegui **salvar** o conteúdo rtf em uma string, da seguinte forma:

*arquivo.aspx*

```
string t1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASPxRichEdit1.SaveCopy(DocumentFormat.Rtf));
```